# Using react-hook-form with @mui/x-date-pickers v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datepicker, react-hook-form

With MUI v5 date pickets I used to do the following to register the input with react-hook-form

```
<DatePicker
    ...date picker props
    renderInput={(params) => {
        return (
            <TextField
                {...params}
                ...other text field props
                {...register("startDate", { required: true })}
            />
        );
    }}
/>
```

Now with MUI v6, the renderInput method is not present so I tried the following:

```
<DatePicker
    ...date picker props
    slotProps={{
        textField: {
            ...text field props,
            {...register("startDate", { required: true })}
        }
    }}
/>
```

Haven't been able to find a lot of documentation around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working using a Controller

```
<Controller
    name="startDate"
    control={control}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    defaultValue={null}
    render={({ field }) =>
        <DatePicker
            {...field}
            ...date picker props
            slotProps={{
                textField: {
                    ...text field props
                }
            }}
        />
    }
/>
```

If anyone has another way to get this working without using a Controller please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with react-hook-form 7.43.9 and @mui/x-date-pickers 6.3.1. After whole day of searching, custom DateInput component for my form was created.

```
import * as React from "react";

import {
    useController,
    useFormContext
} from "react-hook-form";

import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";

interface IProps {
    label: string;
    name: string;
}

export const DateInput = ({ label, name }: IProps) => {
    const { control } = useFormContext();
    const { field } = useController({ control, name, defaultValue: null });
            
    return <DatePicker
        label={label}
        maxDate={new Date()}
        value={field.value}
        onChange={field.onChange}
        slotProps={{
            textField: {
                ...{ readOnly: true }
            }
        }}
    />;
};
```